# Can't update nodejs on Centos 7 with webmin

Tags: node.js, centos7

I'm running a Centos 7 server with Webmin where I've install Nodejs with Node-source repo.

From last week I can't update to nodejs-10.22.0-1nodesource.x86 due to what it seems to be a checksum problem :

```
    Downloading packages:
    Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
    nodejs-10.22.0-1nodesource.x86 FAILED    MB/s |  18 MB  00:00:00 ETA 
    https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_10.x/el/7/x86_64/nodejs-10.22.0-1nodesource.x86_64.rpm:
    [Errno -1] Le paquet ne correspond pas au téléchargement attendu. 
    Suggestion : exécutez yum --enablerepo=nodesource clean metadata
    Essai d'un autre miroir.
    
    Error downloading packages:
      2:nodejs-10.22.0-1nodesource.x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
```

I've tried to clean the cache with `yum --enablerepo=nodesource clean metadata` or `yum clean all` but nothing works.

Has anyone got this error too ?

Here is the yum repo used :

```
    [nodesource]
    name=Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
    baseurl=https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_10.x/el/7/$basearch
    failovermethod=priority
    enabled=1
    gpgcheck=1
    gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/NODESOURCE-GPG-SIGNING-KEY-EL
```

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if this is too late of a reply but I had issues with this too and found removing nodejs and npm first helped. These are the commands I used;

```
sudo yum install -y gcc-c++ make curl
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo yum remove -y nodejs npm
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum list available nodejs
sudo yum install -y nodejs
```